# Create Multiple Files having huge data, and Merge them to one file using .NET

Tags: c#, sql, merge

MY requirement is that, I have Multiple database ( lets say 3). 
I would be creating a file be of any format( I am open to format ), from each database. Each database is geographically seperated out each on one Data Centre(So no scope of Cross-Site HIT ).The file Size would be high ( Approximate 3Million records ) in one file from SQL Database.

So now we have 3 files created, finally I want to Merge these 3 files.

I would need suggestions on the same :

- Which File format should i create(eg csv,xml), such that creation
  of individual file would be easy considering volume.
- Once individual files are created, it will be easy to merge 3
  files. ( what mechanism can be used for merging activity). ( total
  records    will be 9Millon in merged file)

Any pointers will be of great help.

Will be using C#, SQL

Answer (score -1):

Does your server/pc running the program have enough memory to hold all the data in memory first?

My approach would be acquiring all data (from separate sources) via code, merge it there and write to file.

Can you map it to a model?
If you provide each model with a 'ToCsvString()' method I would work as following:

```
var modelList1 = Model1.acquireData(); //Gets all records as CSV String
var modelList2 = Model2.acquireData();
var modelList3 = Model3.acquireData();

MyFileWriter.MergeAndWrite(modelList1,modelList2,modelList3);
```

The File writer would then be something as

```
class MyFileWriter{
    Public static void MergeandWrite(params List<string> list){
         var hugeStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         foreach(var singleList : list){
             foreach(var singleItem : singleList){
                 hugeStringBuilder.append(singleItem);
             }
         }
    }

   File.WriteAllText("path/to/somewhere.csv",hugeStringBuilder.ToString())

}
```

Comment: No, I dont want to hold all data in one memory nor does my system is good to handle this.Also the problem is all 3 database are different sites ( geographically seperated), so I do not want to make cross DB\Site call.